# How to clone elements and their associated event callbacks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clone

I am cloning an element and adding it to the DOM.  I expected that `this` within the newly created cloned element would refer to itself, but it appears to refer to the original clone element.

To illustrate, I created the following script.  By clicking "cloneIt", a new element is added, and upon clicking the new element, `this` refers to the original clone.  My desire was for `data('type')` to display "added".

How do I clone an element and have the callback pertain to the newly cloned object?

https://stackoverflow.com/

```
$('.fileupload').fileupload({
    start: function (e, data) {
        console.log('start', this, $(this).parent().data('type'));
    }
})
    .on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    console.log('fileuploadsubmit', this, $(this).parent().data('type'));
});

$('#cloneIt').click(function () {
    $('#clone').clone(true).removeAttr('id').data('type', 'added').appendTo('#container');
});

#clone {
    display:none;
}

<button id="cloneIt">cloneIt</button>
<ul id="container">
    <li id="clone" data-type="clone">
        <input class="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />
    </li>
    <li data-type="existing">
        <input class="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're after exactly but if you define `$('.fileupload')` and *then* create a clone, it will not be included. Changing the data attribute only seems to work when using `.attr('data-type', 'added')`.

Comment: @Shikkediel  `.attr()` provides the same results.  See http://jsfiddle.net/fq4rqc1u/5/.  I am applying `$('.fileupload')` to both `#clone` as well as the single other `input` which has `data-type` of `existing`, and both of these seem to work. When I clone, however, it stays with the existing data value.  Maybe some sort of callback function instead of directly accessing `this`?

Comment: What does `console.log($(this).parent().index());` log?

Comment: @Roamer-1888  Edit: `0`.

Comment: OK, that conforms what you're saying - `this` in the start callback reliably point to the original element, not the clone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the start callback's notion of `this` gets locked in when `.fileupload()` is invoked, and that `this` is carried forward to the clone.

Personally I would keep the template LI separate from the live LIs, and never invoke `.fileupload()` on it.

**HTML**

```
<button id="cloneIt">cloneIt</button>
<ul id="template">
    <li data-type="original">
        <input class="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="container">
    <li data-type="existing">
        <input class="fileupload" name="file" type="file" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#template {
    display:none;
}
```

Initially, invoke `.fileupload()` only on the INPUTs in `#container`, and subsequently on any clone of the template after it is made.

**Javascript**

```
$('#container .fileupload').fileupload({
    start: function (e, data) {
        console.log('start', this, $(this).parent().data('type'));
    }
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    console.log('fileuploadsubmit', this, $(this).parent().data('type'));
});

$('#cloneIt').click(function () {
    $('#template li').clone().data('type', 'clone').appendTo('#container').find('.fileupload').fileupload(...);
});
```

I would recommend this approach with *any* plugin. Cloning a widgetized element is dangerous. Clone behaviour is not guaranteed to be reliable. With some plugins, you may get away with it; with others, you won't.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/1as47aeb/5/

Seems like you need to call the `fileupload` method from the library again, after creating the DOM object.

If you inspect the DOM in your code, you will see that the attribute is there, added, and you can query it inside your original code after cloning.

EDIT

Corrected behavior in which both input events called when uploading in clone input.

Comment: Thanks Niloct,  Yes, I am sure doing so will work.  It does seem, however, that it should be possible to access the newly created element's DOM from the originally cloned element.

Comment: You can. But it seems that the initialization of fileupload is needed for it too. The attribute is there you can inspect the DOM, commenting the fileupload I introduced in the bottom of code, and you will see.